# WebDriver Adds a <br> for every <br />

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am scraping a webpage with selenium.

This is the code:

```
IWebElement divlink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/ul[2]/li/div[1]"));
//Console.WriteLine(divlink.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
postcontent = divlink.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
postcontent = postcontent.Replace("'", "''");
```

And i have the next problem:

It is adding a `<br>` for every `<br />` and result on 4 line jumps...

I tryed replacing: `postcontent = postcontent.Replace("<br />", "");`

But no result...

---

The Original HTML shows:

```
Podríamos exponer aquí nuestras experiencias con la compra de productos en tiendas on-line, para así saber cual es la que más compensa.<br />
<br />
Lista de tiendas on-line:<br />
<br />
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://asetech.dvdadvdr.net" target="_blank">ddd</a> CD's, DVD's y grabadoras. Cumplen bien.<br />
<br />
```

The Scraped HTML shows:

```
Podríamos exponer aquí nuestras experiencias con la compra de productos en tiendas on-line, para así saber cual es la que más compensa.<br><br />
<br><br />
Lista de tiendas on-line:<br><br />
<br><br />
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://asetech.dvdadvdr.net" target="_blank">ddd</a> CD's, DVD's y grabadoras. Cumplen bien.<br><br />
<br><br />
```

Comment: If you want to get only text inside an element why are you not using `divlink.Text` ?? There is no need to replace any HTML tag. Thanks